# What animals were in Eden?

Tags: eden

Is there any mention of actually what animals were in Eden? Is any mentioned beside the serpent? Is there any  mention of what animals were eaten, if any?

Comment: From my own reading of the first three chapters of Genesis, I would answer in the negative to all three of your questions. What did you find in your own reading ?

Comment: I have no idea what 'clash' you mean. After 50 years of studying the scripture, I have yet to find one single 'clash'.

Comment: Eden is the 'place' of God's provision. Eden is the 'place' where he is found. Eden is the 'place' where God speaks. Eden is the 'place' where cherubim settle. _He dwelleth the cherubim._

Comment: Eden WAS different - it was a beautiful garden. Polar bears could no more survive in that part of the world that was Eden than penguines, but that doesn't mean they didn't exist. The Bible is clear - Adam and Eve were the pinacle, the last, of God's creative activities. After Adam and Eve were driven out of Eden they had to cultivate the ground and struggle, by the sweat of their brows, to live.  They were driven out because they disobeyed their Creator God.  I agree with NigelJ - there is no 'clash' - and I've been studying the Bible for 22 years.

Comment: @user157860 - No, I make no comment on your idea that Eden did not have any dangerous beasts nor poisonous plants, bacteria or viruses.  The Bible does not say which animals were in Eden, and it is silent on whether there were any dangerous wild beasts. All the Bible says is that after the flood the animals became fearful of humans and humans were given permission to kill and eat animals. We can speculate as much as we like, but speculation won't get us anywhere. All I can honestly comment on is what's in the Bible - and if it isn't in the Bible I should keep my opinions to myself.

Answer (score 3):

No, only that after God created Adam he was tasked with naming the beasts of the field and all the birds of the air: “He [God] brought them to the man to see what he would name them; and whatever the man called each living creature, that was its name.  So the man gave names to all the livestock, the birds of the air and all the beasts of the field” (Genesis 2:19-20).

The only mention of eating animals is in Genesis 9:3 and this is after Noah and his family emerge from the Ark: “The fear and dread of you will fall upon all the beasts of the earth and all the birds of the air, upon every creature that moves along the ground, and upon all the fish of the sea; they are given into your hands.  Everything that lives and moves will be food for you.  Just as I gave you the green plants, I now give you everything”.   This suggests that meat was now permissible to eat.

There is no clash with the creation account that I can see.  All the land, sea and air creatures had been created by the time God created Adam.

Comment: The Genesis account of creation does not tell us what animals were created, only that Adam named them.  It's only later, after the flood, that the Bible says animals were given as food to be eaten.  Perhaps Adam and Eve were vegetarians? The Bible says nothing about how or when humans "invented" fire and started to cook meat. It says nothing because it isn't important. Speculation on dietary habits and how food was cooked is pointless. As for asking what was the point in creating animals if they weren't needed for work or for eating, you might as well ask what was the point in creating humans.